# Which event listner should I use? (if value of ng model xy='bla', change it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, events, directive

My goal: 
Input field for end date:

```
<input class="input-sm form-control" unlimited-input="" ng-model="something.EndDate" placeholder="{{'PLACEHOLDER_DDMMYYYY' | translate}}" ng-change-on-blur="updateSomething(something)">
```

Directive unlimitedInput:

```
app.directive('unlimitedInput', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            var unlimitedEndValue = "31.12.2099";
            var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel); // get the value of ng-model
            var oldValue = getter(scope);


            elm.on('load', function() { 
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = 'unlimited';
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                });
            });

            elm.on('focus',function() {
                if(oldValue==unlimitedEndValue){
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = '';
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    });
                }
            });

            elm.on('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var newValue = elm.val();
                    if ((newValue != '') && (newValue!=oldValue)){
                    }else if(newValue == ''){
                        ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = oldValue;
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The Problem is the first event listener (load, ready does not work also), it does not work at all. What I want to achieve: when ng-model has a value and it is 31.12.2099 the user should see "unlimited". Blur and Focus work fine!

Thank you and sorry for my english, if something is not clear, ask:D

**Update**:

Now I have reached what I wanted, but one thing. I want to update the 'something.UnlimitedEnd' (unlimited in the input field) from the directive. I already tried with setter ($parse ...), I get the error, that "something" ia read only. In my understanding I achieve through scope:true I create a child sope with the two way binding, so scope.unlimited = false should work. My new problem is it assigns the value 'false' only in the directive scope also only one way binding. **What I want now to achieve is two way binding for unlimited.**

input field

```
 <input class="input-sm form-control" unlimited-input ng-model="something.EndDate" placeholder="{{'PLACEHOLDER_DDMMYYYY' | translate}}"
                                                   ng-change-on-blur="dosomething(something)"  unlimited="something.UnlimitedEnd"/>
```

Part of the directive:

```
restrict: 'EA',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) return;
            var unlimitedEndValue = "31.12.2099";
            var getter = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
            var unlimitedGetter = $parse(attrs.unlimited);
            var oldValue = getter(scope);


            function setUnlimited(){
                if(getter(scope)==unlimitedEndValue){
                    return 'unlimited';
                }else{
                    return oldValue;
                }
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(setUnlimited);

            elm.on('focus',function() {
                if(oldValue==unlimitedEndValue){
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue('');
                        scope.unlimited = should be updated!! so set false
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    });
                }
            });

            elm.on('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    var newValue = elm.val();
                    if(newValue == ''){
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                        ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = oldValue;
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }else if(newValue=='unlimited' || unlimitedGetter(scope)){
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(unlimitedEndValue);
                        ngModelCtrl.$modelValue = unlimitedEndValue;
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: Which behavior do you expect? Shall it change on the spot or just at blur and focus? What value shall be stored in the model. modelValue != viewModel. - To achieve the right behavior you can also use angular formatter, parser and validator.

Comment: a new question accured, could you maybe read my updated state, do you have any Idea?